# Installing BURG on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, burg

A while back I was dual booting win 7 and 12.04 and had BURG running just fine. A couple months later I messed up my 12.04 partition and decided the easiest way to fix the problem would be to install 12.10. I did that and now I cannot seem to find a way to get burg reinstalled.

My question is has anyone done it successfully? If so, could you please help me get that set up?

Comment: Since you are a new user, I will remind you to click the "Mark As Answer" button by the answer (if any) that you feel best solves your question.  Remember, you can always hit the "comment" button to ask for additional clarification.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, it's exactly the same as 12.04.  You shouldn't have too much trouble:

Try following the directions on [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg) and execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg`.  Note that if it isn't giving you any packages to download, you might need to change the APT line from Software Sources to ask for an older version (lucid will probably do it).

**EDIT:** If you really want to get into it and/or have problems with finding the right PPA/.deb's to get it from, that page also has instructions for compiling it from source.

Comment: (BURG is not the most well-maintained program the world has ever seen.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will serve Latin America : [(Tutorial)Como instalar Burg en Ubuntu 12.10](http://www.taringa.net/posts/linux/15861834/_Tutorial_Como-instalar-Burg-en-Ubuntu-12_10.html)